# Why max(df$date) works but df %>% select(date) %>% max() gives Errors?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, tidyverse

I am working with covid data that includes a date field as character.

I was trying to find the **max date** and I tried commands using dplyr which gave me error:
`df %>% select(date) %>% max()`

`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables`

Where as `max(df$date)` this runs perfectly and gave me results: `[1] "2020-08-17"`.

I am not able to understand why this is happening. Here is the code for data etc.:

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

### Data

```
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RamiKrispin/coronavirus/master/csv/coronavirus.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)

head(df)
```

```
dim(df)
```

```
df %>% distinct(country)
```

```
typeof(df$date)
```

```
df %>% select(date) %>% max()
```

```
df %>% max(date)
```

```
max(df$date)
```

Comment: Try: `select(date) %>% mutate(max(date))`

Comment: Try: `pull(date) %>% max()`, `pull` returns a vector instead of a tibble like `select`

Comment: @Duck but this gives me a column of repetitive max Date values. I just need to find 1 max value out of all and that should work without mutate

Comment: when you try to do that u get error: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables`. And if all variables are numeric then you will get maximum in all data.frame not for each column.

Comment: Thanks @starja `pull(date) %>% max()` worked. But if I am working on a data frame and select a column why that turns into a tibble. After using Pandas from Python I find some very different styles here and I guess it will take me some time to get used to of this pull() command here

Comment: @det but I already subset it to single column which is of char type

Comment: @ViSa `select` always returns data.frame, in this case with 1 column - date. If you want to take column of data.frame as vector in pipeline then you can use `pluck`, ex. `df %>% purrr::pluck("date")`.

Comment: Thank you @det . I will try using pluck from next time. Thanks for letting me know!!

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens because you still have a dataframe object when you use `select`. If you want to subset so you only have the vector with the date variable (as is done when using `df$date`) using dplyr, you can use `df %>% pull(date) %>% max()`

Comment: @"Josh C" Yes that worked. I need to be more careful with this `pull` statement in future.